# Using grep to find a specific number in between other numbers

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I'm trying to find any and all 3 digit integers in a text file who's middle number is 7 using the grep command. I know how to find all 3 digit integers (grep '^[0-9]{3}$' textfile.txt) but not how to specify which ones have a middle digit of 7. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using regular expression?

Comment: You are thinking about this too hard. You know how to match a single digit. You know how to match a `7`. Just put those two things together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep -P which will take regex

```
grep -P "\d7\d" filename
```